# Testing ActiveCell with Index Match, results always True

Tags: excel, vba, indexing, match

first of all, thank you all, your questions and answers have been of great value over the years, but now i've run into a problem of which I'm just not seeing/finding the solution.
Edit: before i even asked the question: solved big part of my question already, but now i have 1 issue remaining. I'll leave the details below in, just for clarity.

Document layout:

- Sheet1: Overview (gets renewed every week or so, on command).
  Contains array of (text) data A:Z, approx 3k lines.
  Column A contains the unique identifier, for the contents of said row.
- Sheet2: Backup (contains exact backup, pre-update of Overview)

Goal:
Loop through all unique identifiers (Col.A) and test B:Z with respect to B:Z on Sheet2, the backup, with an INDEX/MATCH. If the value of the backup is different, add that value as a Note(comment) to the ActiveCell.

Created a small testworkbook, with the following data on Sheet1 -and- Sheet2:

| Unique | V1 | V2 | V3 | V4 |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 212223 | B | C | D | E |
| 212224 | F | G | H | I |
| 212238 | J* | K | L | M |

*Cell B4 on Sheet1 was updated to "Z".

Now i got pretty much everything working, except my comparing the ActiveCell offset to the Index/Match result. I'm looping through my range in Col A, checking each following column for it's matching value on Sheet2. When i arrive at the following point in the code, my activecell is A2. Condensed down, looks like this:

```
Sub CellCheck()


Dim NewNote As Variant 'Note-Content to be
Dim ActiveCell_Debug As Variant
Dim col As Integer 'Starting Column Counter
    
col = 1
'Start at cell A2
ActiveCell_Debug = ActiveCell.Address


If ActiveCell.Offset(0, col).Value <> "INDEX(Sheet2!$B:$B, MATCH(Sheet1!" & ActiveCell_Debug & ",Sheet2!A:A,0))" Then
    NewNote = Application.Evaluate("INDEX(Sheet2!$B:$B, MATCH(Sheet1!" & ActiveCell_Debug & ",Sheet2!A:A,0))")

    ActiveCell.Offset(0, col).AddComment
    ActiveCell.Offset(0, col).Comment.Text Text:=NewComment
    'ActiveCell.Offset(0, col).DisplayCommentIndicator = -1
End If
End Sub
```

Now "ActiveCell.Offset(0, col).Value" is "B".
And "INDEX(Sheet2!$B:$B, MATCH(Sheet1!" & ActiveCell_Debug & ",Sheet2!A:A,0))" is -also- "B".

But 'NewNote' is now also "B".

If i make Cell A4 the Activecell, result is "J" as expected. So, no matter what the test is always true.
What am i missing here?

Many thanks in advance.

Comment: You're comparing a cell to the literal text of the formula, not the result of computing that formula.

Comment: Does `NewNote` return what you need? If yes, you should move the line giving it a value above `If ActiveCell.Offset(0, col).Value <>...` and transform this one in `If ActiveCell.Offset(0, col).Value <> NewNote`. Otherwise, you should use the VBA way to calculate the comparing value.

Comment: Is "Sheet2" the `ActiveSheet`, as it looks? If yes, I can show you how your sheet formula can be transformed in a VBA one.

Comment: Oh dear, how embarrassing. Totally missed it. Rory was right. Just add 'evaluate( ... )' and it works.